# LiveRail VAST/VPAID XML for HTML5 player Samples for Testing

Tags: html, vast, liverail

I'm looking for some samples of VAST XML/tag with VPAID to test VPAID implementation for HTML5 player working with LiveRail Ad Server.
On [iab.net](http://www.iab.net/guidelines/508676/digitalvideo/vast/vast_xml_samples) I found the samples without VPAID. Also [test.liverail.com](http://test.liverail.com/player/index.php?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1331&LR_TAGS=vpaid)
contains VAST examples with VPAID for flash only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One example of HTML+JS VPAID: http://rtr.innovid.com/r1.5554946ab01d97.36996823;cb=%25%CACHEBUSTER%25%25

We have other examples we used to test our plugin implementation:
http://mailonline.github.io/videojs-vast-vpaid

Answer (score 0):

You can find a bunch of JS VPAID ad examples here: https://github.com/ryanthompson591/vpaidExamples/

If you need the VAST tags, you can get them from here: http://ryanthompson591.github.io/vpaidExamples/